# Python dict items matching returns TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code that I want to match user input of x and y values multiplied result to match the dictionary items. For example the user inputs x=2 and y=3, the multiplication result will be 6. the order of the x and y values is important and it should match the dictionary order. For example x=3 and y=2 are not the same despite the fact that they have similar multiplication values.
therefore, I want a function that match this multiplied value with dictionary items in order to give it some grading. Here the code that outputs typeError: 'int' object is not iterable.:

```
    scoremapDict = {(1, 1): 1, (1, 2): 2, (2, 1): 2, (1, 3): 3, (3, 1): 3, (1, 4): 4, (4, 1): 4,      (2, 2): 4, (1, 5): 5,
  (5, 1): 5, (4, 2): 8, (2, 4): 8, (2, 3): 6, (3, 2):6, (3, 3): 9, (2, 5): 10, (5, 2):10, (3,    4): 12,
  (4, 3):12, (3, 5): 15, (5, 3): 15, (4, 4): 16, (4, 5): 20, (5, 4): 20, (5, 5): 25}


    x = 5
    y = 2
    results = int(x*y)
    for i in results:
     if results == scoremapDict[(x,y)]:
        print("High")
    else:
        print("None")
```

Can anyone help this tyro python-er please, thanks in advance:

Comment: `results` is a number (10) and you cant iterate over it. Try `for i in range(1,results)`

Comment: Why do you have to iterate through `results` here?

Comment: thanks mr balderman for your prompt response. sorry I am new to python but the result that I want to obtain is i want to match user inpout like x and y values with predefined dictionary values and their score values. For example inside the dictionary if there are (1,2) their score value is 2. If the user input value matches that I Will grade the number 2 use a certain word based on predifined criteria. this one gives me a long range of "high", I dont want that I want to give it one grade in the print. Regards

Comment: I don't want to iterate it. All I want is to match dictionary values the tuples(5, 2)  and their multiplication value 10 to match the input of x = 5 and y=2 results in order to give it a grade of negligible, high, extreme, mediulm and low based on result values.

Comment: mr vnk thanks for asking. I am using the dictionary because it is hard to use 25 dictionary items to match with x and y product values using 25  if elif statements which is usually used for grading purposes. It will be long. I hope you understand my objective writing this code.